# How to fix: Error- No database selected

Tags: php, mysql

SERVER RESPONSE

Error: INSERT INTO epiz_19848473_Liste1 (Rowcount, Level1) VALUES (0, 'any Value')
No database selected

PHP CODE

**UPDATE**

```
<?php
$servername = "sql308.epizy.com";
$username = "epiz_19848473";
$password = "huihuibuh";
$dbname = "Liste1";<--UPDATED

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO Liste1 <--UPDATED (Rowcount, Level1)
VALUES (0, 'any Value')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

This should work, right?

NEW STATUS
Connection failed: Access denied for user 'epiz_19848473'@'192.168.0.%' to database 'Liste1'

Comment: `$dbname` has no value.

Comment: Where `$dbname` defined?

Comment: I didn't want to create a new tabel, so I deleted the "new" in the $conn. It doesn't do anything at the moment ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did not defined the database name in the connection

```
<?php
$servername = "sql308.epizy.com";
$username = "epiz_19848473";
$password = "huihuibuh";
$dbname = "DATABASE_NAME_HERE";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

else you can define define the database name in the connection

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, "DATABASE_NAME_HERE");
```

Comment: I didn't want to create a new tabel, so I deleted the "new" in the $conn. It doesn't do anything at the moment ...

Comment: in $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database) , new does not mean creating new table or database it is used for creating new connection, "$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);" this is used in "MySQLi Object-Oriented" else you can use "MySQLi Procedural" , "$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);"

Comment: How do I execute the php file with a add Event Listener?

Comment: you can create a form then in the end call a submit or add button and redirect the form to the php page

Answer (score 1):

The code is perfectly all right , the problem is with mysql configuration .

Please login to mysql as **root user ** and do the following,

1. GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'epiz_19848473'@'192.168.0.%' (use ip of php server)
2. FLUSH PRIVILIGES;

The above allows the user to connect to mysql table from the ip specified.

Comment: what do you mean by root? At the moment it's not showing any respoonse

Answer (score 0):

Just define the dbname,like this:

```
<?php
$servername = "sql308.epizy.com";
$username = "epiz_19848473";
$password = "huihuibuh";
$dbname = "test";   //You should create this db in mysql
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use This:

```
CREATE TABLE [database_name].[table_name] ( 
      [your_table_things]
);
```